# How do I define a vector of chrono::DateTime with different TimeZones?

Tags: rust

I am working with the `chrono` library, and do not know how to define a struct field that is a vector of `DateTime<Tz: TimeZone>` structs with a `TimeZone` trait instead of a concrete type.

I.e, I can do:

```rust
use chrono::{DateTime, TimeZone, Utc}; // 0.4.11

pub struct ItemSchedule {
    pub times: Vec<Box<DateTime<Utc>>>,
}
```

When I try to use a trait object:

```rust
use chrono::{DateTime, TimeZone, Utc}; // 0.4.11

pub struct ItemSchedule {
    pub times: Vec<Box<DateTime<dyn TimeZone>>>,
}
```

I get an error:

```
error[E0191]: the value of the associated type `Offset` (from trait `chrono::offset::TimeZone`) must be specified
 --> src/lib.rs:4:37
  |
4 |     pub times: Vec<Box<DateTime<dyn TimeZone>>>,
  |                                     ^^^^^^^^ help: specify the associated type: `TimeZone<Offset = Type>`
```

Looking at the code, the `TimeZone` trait has an associated type called `Offset`, which has to implement a trait called `Offset`. I also get errors if I attempt to specify this the type declaration.

Comment: I meant to answer your question but also got caught up in the type errors when trying to get dynamic dispatch working. In case you only want to store times belonging to the same timezone in an `ItemSchedule`, plain old static dispatch should work: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ea602947e22114c9c9ca5ac8cad309c4 However, that's probably not what you wanted.

Comment: I think a decent workaround is to convert everything to UTC, regardless of the original timezone, but I feel that this should be possible

Comment: I filed an issue related to this: "How to store TimeZone in Arc?" https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/issues/432 .